# MyISAM, Cron, ERROR

Tags: wordpress, database, error, 4.7, cron

I get this error on installing the CiviCRM plugin for Wordpress (Wordpress version 4.4.2, CiviCRM 4.7.4)

System Status: Error

MyISAM Database Engine

Cron Not Running

Configure Default Mailbox

Complete Setup

There is no CiviCRM Menu and nothing else appears.
Error page appears as this;

Welcome to your Home Dashboard

Your dashboard provides a one-screen view of the data that's most important to you. Graphical or tabular data is pulled from the reports you select, and is displayed in 'dashlets' (sections of the dashboard).
Access Keys: 
Powered by CiviCRM 4.7.4. System Status: Error CiviCRM is openly available under the GNU AGPL License.

Comment: Found Similar issue reported here on CiviCRM JIRA [link](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18009) and [link](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17894)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was found in another Question with similar responses.

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/9792/3016

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have several errors listed. I would start by addressing the most serious first. You'll need to reinstall CiviCRM after enabling the InnoDB database engine in your MySQL instance (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql).

Comment: It seems that its already enabled. Using a hosted VPS for this and all looks OK.

Comment: Try removing all tables from the database with names  beginning with civicrm_. It may be easiest to do this by restoring a backup from prior to the CiviCRM installation. Alternatively, try running the MySQL command Drop table xxxx; for every civicrm table, replacing xxxx with the table name. Then delete the civicrm.settings.php file which you can find from https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CMS+Standard+Directories+and+File+locations#CMSStandardDirectoriesandFilelocations-CiviCRMsettingsfile.2.

Comment: Hmm, every table starts with civicrm_

Comment: Removed the SQL database and the custom.settings.php and reinstalled with the same error.