# Dashboard Issue after attempted Installation on Wordpress 4.5

Tags: wordpress, installation, dashboard

Attempting to install CiviCRM 4.7.6 on WP 4.5. Plugin activates fine. All checks on Installation screen are fine/OK.

On finish, there was a note about "Cron not running", but no error that was obvious.

The civicrm.settings.php file is not present in the installation.

When I click on CiviCRM to view the dashboard - It opens, but does not display the dashboard and no menu. None of the links go anywhere.

Any help is appreciated!

Near the bottom is an error message: 
Powered by CiviCRM 4.7.6. System Status: Error
The Error link is a dead end/circular to the same page.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please close this. The solution is here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus

Answer (score 0):

> The civicrm.settings.php file is not present in the installation.

you can use the command "locate civicrm.settings.php " on your command line  to see if you can find it because on wordpress you can have the settings file floating somewhere probably and the installation cannot run to completion if the settings file is not there "( so i think )"

you could also get to see some compatibility issues which have been stated [Wordpress plugin incompatible with CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+plugins+incompatible+with+CiviCRM)  to see if you have an issue related to those.

If it takes so much time, you can take a lesser time to follow this [Installing CiviCRM on wordpress](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5) which is very explicit and well elaborate

Comment: The solution is here:
http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus

It has to do with the directory structure on the install. I was able to get it the Dashboard to render after editing the civicrm.settings.php file.