# Issue with Installation Dashboard Not Visible

Tags: installation

[image]I've installed CiviCRM 4.7.6 onto a WP v4.5 site. It appears successful until I open the Dashboard. At that point, the dashboard does not render (no menu and no content). See the attached screen shot. Clicking on System Status: Error brings me right back to this same Dashboard. There is NO CLUE as to the issue.

When I first installed, there was also a message about Cron not running, but I still got a success message for installation.

Please help! This is the 2nd time in 2 days I'm asking for help - no response to my first message.

Comment: Please close this. Solution is here:
http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus