# Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php

Tags: wordpress, error, 4.7, 4.7.10

running CiviCRM WordPress 4.7.7

Any ideas what **normalize your directory structure** means?

Given it knows where the database is and both the website and the backend are working I am unsure where this is coming from. It only appears in the error_log.

> [error] [client 66.249.83.121] PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. Please boot with settingsFile, search, or CIVICRM_SETTINGS; or normalize your directory structure.' in /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php:125
>
> Stack trace:
>
> > 1. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php(413): Civi\Cv\Bootstrap->boot()
> > 2. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/open.php(2): require_once('/var/www/vhosts...')
> > 3. {main}\n  thrown in /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php on line 125

**Update 1:**
*civicrm_config.php - getCivicrmSettingsPhp*
Added error_log to display the options parameter and got the following:

> [dynamicSettingsFile] => /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/settings_location.php\n
>   [env] => CIVICRM_SETTINGS\n
>   [prefetch] => 1\n
>   [settingsFile] => \n
>   [search] => 1\n
>   [cmsType] => \n
>   [httpHost] => casem-acmse.org\n)\n

Shouldn't the file referred to in dynamicSettingsFile be civicrm_settings.php?

Comment: This is still occurring in 4.7.11

Answer (score 3):

This is related to [Word Press Install Missing civicrm.settings.php; dashboard unavailable; no menus](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/word-press-install-missing-civicrm-settings-php-dashboard-unavailable-no-menus/9792#9792)

I suspect that the culprit is the userFrameworkResourceURL  I would tray the overrides mentioned in the above thread

Comment: I added an update to my original post. Shouldn't the file referred to in **dynamicSettingsFile** be civicrm_settings.php? I was under the impression settings_location.php was deprecated prior to 4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error message.  Using Codedogs' change didn't work for me, not sure why.
In my case, I simply hardcoded the 'settingsFile' as follows:

```
'settingsFile' => /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php',
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you edit this to make it clear which file you edited?  That will help future visitors to this post.

Comment: The reason it did not work is that your **civicrm.settings.php** file is located in the **uploads** folder. Mine is located in the **plugins/civicrm** folder which is what `dirname(__DIR__)` evaluates to.

Answer (score 0):

The following edit corrects the problem:
 **/../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm_config.php**

```
 public static function singleton() {
    if (self::$singleton === NULL) {
      self::$singleton = new Bootstrap(array(
        'dynamicSettingsFile' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/settings_location.php',
        'env' => 'CIVICRM_SETTINGS',
        'prefetch' => TRUE,
        'settingsFile' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/civicrm.settings.php', <=== CHANGE THIS LINE
        'search' => TRUE,
        'cmsType' => NULL,
        'httpHost' => array_key_exists('HTTP_HOST', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '',
      ));
    }
    return self::$singleton;
  }
```

Comment: This error still occurs in 4.7.10. I had to propagate the above fix to make **CRON not run** go away.