# Menu bar is missing

Tags: menu

I am missing the CiviCRM menu bar. I looked into the resource url (should that end in wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm or .org.au/ ?, and should it be https or http if i have ssl certification?).

I've installed the CiviCRM Admin Utilities plugin and this kind of overcomes the issue. But i would like to get the menu to work. It seems more intuitive. I for example can't find a way to add a new organisation with the CiviCRM Admin Utilities alternative.

I'm running 5.5.2 wordpress and 5.15.1 civicrm

thank you for your help,
JD

Comment: Possibly a solution here:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12329/menu-bar-missing-on-fresh-civicrm-on-wordpress?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you  Cleanup Caches and Update Paths? It worked for me. Get to it from here: wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1

Comment: I upgraded three sites from v5.50.3 to v5.51.1 (on WordPress v6.01) and the top menu bar disappeared on all of them. Using the link above, I did the clear cache and then reset paths and the menu bars came back.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL is set correctly in /var/www/yoursite/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php (or whatever the path is to yout site)  I have cloned sites to use for dev and forgotten to change this.  It can cause all sorts of issues including a loss of the CiviCRM navigation header.

if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://yourCiviSite.org/');
}

Comment: This is easy to forget if you make a copy of your site for backup or development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an answer but somehow the same problem, although I think my problem is connected to Drupal as host.

If you do have the same issue, then your menu bar should be on the right place, if you enable **Asset Caching** at Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling.

With enabled Asset Caching your image upload url must be configured properly, to make this work. But I am sorry I don't know the right configuration for this in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing uk.squiffle.kam Plugin?

https://github.com/aydun/uk.squiffle.kam you can reach from.